# Iterating and indexing

Tags: python

I am currently stuck with this program. I am attempting to determine the molecular weight of a compound given the molecular equation (only Cs, Hs, and Os). I also am unsure of how to correctly format [index +1], as I am trying to determine what the next character after "x" is to see if it is a number or another molecule

def main():

```
C1 = 0
H1 = 0
O1 = 0
num = 0

chemicalFormula = input("Enter the chemical formula, or enter key to quit: ")
while True:
    cformula = list(chemicalFormula)
    for index, x in enumerate(cformula):
        if x == 'C':
            if cformula[index + 1] == 'H' or cformula[index + 1] == 'O':
                C1 += 1
            else:
                for index, y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):
                    if cformula[index + 1] != 'H' or cformula[index + 1] != 'O':
                        num = int(y)
                        num = num*10 + int(cformula[index + 1])
                    else:
                        C1 += num
                        break
```

this is the error I keep getting

```
Enter the chemical formula, or enter key to quit: C2
  File "/Users/ykasznik/Documents/ykasznikp7.py", line 46, in main
    for index, y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the inner loop?

Comment: Where exactly you are intending to get `y` from in the inner loop is not clear -- it certainly isn't from the `range()`. Clearing that up would make it possible to give a more definitive answer.

Comment: The TypeError you are getting is because Python is trying to iterate through a single int to assign values to two names.  This was called 'tuple unpacking' and is part of why `a, b = b, a` is valid Python for swapping name values.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `range(index + 1, 1000000000)`. Either you want a possibly unlimited iteration, and you should use `itertools.count(index+1)` or you want to iterate up to the length of the formula: `range(index+1, len(cformula))`. Choosing a random big number is a bad idea and could cause some `IndexError`s.

Answer (score 2):

You should change this line

```
for index, y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):
```

to

```
for y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):
```

Comment: You probably wanted to say "You *should* change...".

Answer (score 1):

Here's my idea on how to solve the problem. Basically, you keep track of the current 'state' and iterate through each character exactly once, so you can't lose track of where you are or anything like that.

```
def getWeightFromChemical(chemical):
    chemicals = {"C" : 6, "H" : 1, "O" : 8}
    return chemicals.get(chemical, 0)

def chemicalWeight(chemicalFormula):
    lastchemical = ""
    currentnumber = ""
    weight = 0

    for c in chemicalFormula:
        if str.isalpha(c): # prepare new chemical
            if len(lastchemical) > 0:
                weight += getWeightFromChemical(lastchemical)*int("1" if currentnumber == "" else currentnumber)
            lastchemical = c
            currentnumber = ""
        elif str.isdigit(c): # build up number for previous chemical
            currentnumber += c

    # one last check
    if len(lastchemical) > 0:
        weight += getWeightFromChemical(lastchemical)*int("1" if currentnumber == "" else currentnumber)

    return weight
```

By the way, can anyone see how to refactor this to not have that piece of code twice? It bugs me.

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided here focus on two different aspects of solving your problem:

1. A very specific solution to your error (`int is not iterable`), by correcting some code.
2. A bit bigger perspective of how to handle your code.

Regarding **1**, a comment to your question noted the issue: the syntax of tuple-unpacking in your inner loop. 
An example of Tuple-unpacking would be

```
a,b = ['a','b']
```

Here, Python would take the first element of the right hand side (RHS) and assign it to the first name on the left hand side (LHS), the second element of RHS and assign it to the second name in the LHF.

Your inner loop that faults, 
`for index, y in range(index + 1, 1000000000)`,
is equivalent of trying to do

```
index, y = 1
```

Now, an integer is not a collection of elements, so this would not work.

Regarding **2**, you should focus on the strategy of **modularization**, which basically means you write a function for each sub-problem. Python was almost born for this. (Note, this strategy does not necessarily mean writing Python-modules for each subproblem.)

In you case, your main goal can be divided into several sub-problems:

1. Getting the molecular sequences.
2. Split the sequences into individual sequences.
3. Splitting the sequence into its H, C, and O-elements.
4. Given the number of H, C and O-atoms, calculate the molecular weight.

Step 3 and 4 are excellent candidates for independent functions, as their core problem is isolated from the remaining context.

Here, I assume we only get 1 sequence at a time, and that they can be of the form:

- `CH4`
- `CHHHH`
- `CP4H3OH`

Step 3:

```
def GetAtoms(sequence):
  ''' 
  Counts the number of C's, H's and O's in sequence and returns a dictionary.
  Only works with a numeric suffices up to 9, e.g. C10H12 would not work.
  '''
  atoms = ['C','H','O']  # list of which atoms we want to count.
  res = {atom:0 for atom in atoms}
  last_c = None
  for c in sequence:
    if c in atoms:
      res[c] += 1
      last_c = c
    elif c.isdigit() and last_c is not None:
      res[last_c] += int(c) - 1
      last_c = None
    else:
      last_c = None
   return res
```

You can see, that regardless of how you obtain the sequence and how the molecular weight is calculated, this method works (under the preconditions). If you later need to extend the capabilities of how you obtain the atom-count, this can be altered without affecting the remaining logic.

Step 4:

```
def MolecularWeight(atoms):
  return atoms['H']*1 + atoms['C']*8 + atoms['O']*18
```

Now your total logic could be this:

```
while True:
  chemicalFormula = input("Enter the chemical formula, or enter key to quit: ")
  if len(chemicalFormula) == 0:
    break

  print 'Molecular weight of', chemicalFormula, 'is', MolecularWeight(GetAtoms(chemicalFormula))
```

Comment: oh wow, you are a lifesaver. I'm going to try and use this answer to help me solve the problem. I dont mean to sound forward/go against etiquette, but if I just copy/paste all of these separate parts under one main in my window would it run it as a function? once again, really new at python and way out of my league right now

Comment: That's the cool part; if you have a `main`-function then these two method definitions do not need to be *within* the `main`-function, but can be defined before or after it! It is only the last codeblock (`while True:...`) that would be in your `main`-function.

Comment: okay so I just tried putting it all together and I still need the first steps haha...any suggestions on directions for the first two?

Comment: What do you expect as input from the user, and do you expect only one molecule per input or multiple molecules per input? If multiple molecules, how do you distinguish the individual molecules?

Comment: Also consider following the Python coding guidelines in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  Specifically, methods and functions start with a lower case character, where class names start with an uppercase character and are in CamelCase.

Comment: distinguishing between the multiple molecules has been what has tripped me up all this time

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for index, y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):
```

to

```
for index, y in enumerate(range(index + 1, 1000000000)):
```

Although you may consider renaming your outer loop or inner loop `index` for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Range returns either a list of int, or an iterable of int, depending on which version of Python you are using.  Attempting to assign that single int into two names causes Python to attempt to iterate through that int in automated tuple unpacking.

So, change the

`for index, y in range(index + 1, y):`

to

`for y in range(index + 1, y):`

Also, you use `index + 1` repeatedly, but mostly to look up the next symbol in your cformula.  Since that doesn't change over the course of your outer loop, just assign it its own name once, and keep using that name:

```
for index, x in enumerate(cformula):
    next_index = index + 1
    next_symbol = cformula[next_index]
    if x == 'C':
        if next_symbol == 'H' or next_symbol == 'O':
            C1 += 1
        else:
            for y in range(next_index, 1000000000):
                if next_symbol != 'H' or next_symbol != 'O':
                    num = y*10 + int(next_symbol)
                else:
                    C1 += num
                    break
```

I've also refactored out some constants to make the code cleaner. Your inner loop as written was failing on tuple assignment, and would only be counting up the `y`.  Also, your index would be reset again once you exited the inner loop, so you would be processing all of your digits repeatedly.

If you want to iterate over the substring after your current symbol, you could just use slice notation to get all of those characters: `for subsequent in cformula[next_index:]`

For example:

```
>>> chemical = 'CH3OOCH3'
>>> chemical[2:]
'3OOCH3'
>>> for x in chemical[2:]:
...     print x
... 
3
O
O
C
H
3
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer has been very helpful. I appreciate you cleaning up my code. Could you elaborate a little on iterating over a substring? It sounds like what I need haha, but to be honest I am extremely new with Python so I don't quite understand what that means

Comment: I extended my answer with an example of using a slice to get a substring of the string through which you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, x in enumerate(cformula):
    if x == 'C':
        if cformula[index + 1] == 'H' or cformula[index + 1] == 'O':
            C1 += 1
        else:
            for index, y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):
```

This is a Really Bad Idea. You are overwriting the value of index from the outer loop with the value of index from the inner loop.
You should use a different name, say `index2` for the inner loop.

Also, when you say `for index, y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):` you are acting as if you are expecting range() to produce a sequence of 2-tuples. But `range` always produces a sequence of `int`s.

Roger has suggested `for y in range(index + 1, 1000000000):` but I think you are intending to get the value of `y` from somewhere else (it's not clear where. Maybe you want to use the second argument of `enumerate()` to specify the value to start from, instead?

That is, 
    for index2, y in enumerate(whereeveryoumeanttogetyfrom, index + 1)

so that index2 equals index +1 on the first step through the loop, index +2 on the second, etc.